# How to override or add custom layout to android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I'm setting a list adapter as follows, and if i just change simple_list_item_activated_1 for lv_layout it doesn't work at all.

any ideas?.

Thanks!

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<DummyContent.DummyItem>(
            getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
            android.R.id.text1,
            DummyContent.ITEMS));
}
```

How can I attach my custom layout called lv_layout to that adapter?

this is my layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/lv_layout"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/size"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/resolution"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you want to use setlistadapter then? You have to create your custom adapter too in that case because serlistapater will only update the textview part of your custom layout and rest part it will ignore which idont think what you want. So 
1.make a customadapter
2.override its getview
3.the set the adapter to your custom layout.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

`android.R.*` are Android's internal resources.

To use your own layouts from `res/layout/` skip the android prefix:

```
R.layout.lv_layout
```

Same goes for ids (if you're wondering).